# Can I chain two Spring batch jobs together?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are using Spring Batch 3.0.8 with Spring Framework 4.  We have defined a number of jobs to be run in quick succession:
Job1 loads-up reference data from remote sources, and 
Job2 processes CSV input file against the reference data loaded in Job1.

Normally we would run Job1 and Job2 separately under operation team's control, but for automatic testing we would like to chain Job1 and Job2 together so that as soon as Job1 finishes processing it will automatically kick off Job2.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is via a Spring Batch Job.  You can use a Job step to launch one job.  Once that finishes, you can use another to launch the second.  Other mechanisms like using listeners can work, but in the use case you're describing, I think this makes the most sense.

Comment: ` Once that finishes, you can use another to launch the second.` - how do I launch a 2nd job?

Comment: I should add that we use CommandLineJobLauncher today to start all our jobs individually (from cmd line) when it's time to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a new job, you can also give a look to [`JobStep`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html).
From it's Javadoc:

> A Step that delegates to a Job to do its work. This is a great tool
>   for managing dependencies between jobs, and also to modularise complex
>   step logic into something that is testable in isolation. The job is
>   executed with parameters that can be extracted from the step
>   execution, hence this step can also be usefully used as the worker in
>   a parallel or partitioned execution.